# nginx ingress-controller error : admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request host and path already defined

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, cert-manager

Test1
I created an ingress with a cert-manager annotation.
This one fails with the following error "nginx ingress-controller error : admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request  host and path already defined "

Test2
I created the same ingress but without the cert-manager annotation.
This one succeeds.

Nginx release

```
$ kubectl exec ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller-7f4db9965c-ht8t9 -- /nginx-ingress-controller --version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v1.1.0
  Build:         cacbee86b6ccc45bde8ffc184521bed3022e7dee
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.9
    
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cert-manager release

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.6.0/cert-manager.yaml
```

Details of test1

```
# cat test-ingress-cert.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sso-production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-staging
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
  namespace: prod
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sso.mydomain.com
    secretName: quickstart-example-tls
  rules:
  - host: sso.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sso
            port:
              number: 8080


# kubectl create -f test-ingress-cert.yaml
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "test-ingress-cert.yaml": 
admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: 
host "sso.mydomain.com" and path "/" is already defined in ingress prod/sso-echopen-tls

# kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE   NAME                  CLASS    HOSTS                                 ADDRESS           PORTS     AGE
prod        gateway-echopen-tls   <none>   gateway.mydomain.com   152.228.169.166   80, 443   7d
prod        hapi-echopen-tls      <none>   hapi.mydomain.com      152.228.169.166   80, 443   9d
prod        reader-echopen-tls    <none>   reader.mydomain.com    152.228.169.166   80, 443   7d

# kubectl get issuers.cert-manager.io  -n prod
NAME                  READY   AGE
letsencrypt-staging   True    87m


# kubectl get all -n cert-manager
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cert-manager-77fd97f598-c54px              1/1     Running   0          138m
pod/cert-manager-cainjector-7974c84449-vx54h   1/1     Running   0          138m
pod/cert-manager-webhook-5f4b965fbd-nccw5      1/1     Running   0          138m

NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/cert-manager           ClusterIP   10.3.44.182   <none>        9402/TCP   138m
service/cert-manager-webhook   ClusterIP   10.3.21.35    <none>        443/TCP    138m

NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/cert-manager              1/1     1            1           138m
deployment.apps/cert-manager-cainjector   1/1     1            1           138m
deployment.apps/cert-manager-webhook      1/1     1            1           138m

NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-77fd97f598              1         1         1       138m
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-cainjector-7974c84449   1         1         1       138m
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-webhook-5f4b965fbd      1         1         1       138m

# kubectl get all -n default
NAME                                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller-7f4db9965c-ht8t9   1/1     Running   0          9d

NAME                                                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                      AGE
service/kubernetes                                     ClusterIP      10.3.0.1      <none>            443/TCP                      89d
service/ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.3.34.184   152.228.169.166   80:30370/TCP,443:31584/TCP   23d
service/ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.3.82.29    <none>            443/TCP                      23d

NAME                                                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           23d

NAME                                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller-764c5b9596   0         0         0       10d
replicaset.apps/ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller-78fdb596f9   0         0         0       9d
replicaset.apps/ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller-7f4db9965c   1         1         1       23d
replicaset.apps/ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller-88fb6466f    0         0         0       9d


# kubectl logs cert-manager-webhook-5f4b965fbd-nccw5 -n cert-manager
W1220 10:28:37.440085       1 client_config.go:615] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
W1220 10:28:37.443639       1 client_config.go:615] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I1220 10:28:37.443841       1 webhook.go:70] cert-manager/webhook "msg"="using dynamic certificate generating using CA stored in Secret resource"  "secret_name"="cert-manager-webhook-ca" "secret_namespace"="cert-manager"
I1220 10:28:37.444238       1 server.go:140] cert-manager/webhook "msg"="listening for insecure healthz connections"  "address"=":6080"
I1220 10:28:37.444330       1 server.go:171] cert-manager/webhook "msg"="listening for secure connections"  "address"=":10250"
I1220 10:28:37.444369       1 server.go:203] cert-manager/webhook "msg"="registered pprof handlers"
I1220 10:28:38.507011       1 dynamic_source.go:273] cert-manager/webhook "msg"="Updated serving TLS certificate"

# kubectl logs cert-manager-77fd97f598-c54px -n cert-manager
I1220 10:28:35.975050       1 start.go:75] cert-manager "msg"="starting controller"  "git-commit"="49914a057b39c887be0974c4657c095bd7724bc7" "version"="v1.6.0"
W1220 10:28:35.975206       1 client_config.go:615] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I1220 10:28:35.977657       1 controller.go:268] cert-manager/controller/build-context "msg"="configured acme dns01 nameservers" "nameservers"=["10.3.0.10:53"]
I1220 10:28:35.978527       1 controller.go:85] cert-manager/controller "msg"="enabled controllers: [certificaterequests-approver certificaterequests-issuer-acme certificaterequests-issuer-ca certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned certificaterequests-issuer-vault certificaterequests-issuer-venafi certificates-issuing certificates-key-manager certificates-metrics certificates-readiness certificates-request-manager certificates-revision-manager certificates-trigger challenges clusterissuers ingress-shim issuers orders]"
I1220 10:28:35.978792       1 controller.go:115] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting leader election"
I1220 10:28:35.979117       1 controller.go:105] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting metrics server"  "address"={"IP":"::","Port":9402,"Zone":""}
I1220 10:28:35.979810       1 leaderelection.go:248] attempting to acquire leader lease kube-system/cert-manager-controller...
I1220 10:29:40.695753       1 leaderelection.go:258] successfully acquired lease kube-system/cert-manager-controller
I1220 10:29:40.696143       1 controller.go:163] cert-manager/controller "msg"="not starting controller as it's disabled" "controller"="certificatesigningrequests-issuer-vault"
I1220 10:29:40.696185       1 controller.go:163] cert-manager/controller "msg"="not starting controller as it's disabled" "controller"="certificatesigningrequests-issuer-venafi"
I1220 10:29:40.696436       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificaterequests-approver"
I1220 10:29:40.696548       1 controller.go:163] cert-manager/controller "msg"="not starting controller as it's disabled" "controller"="certificatesigningrequests-issuer-ca"
I1220 10:29:40.696615       1 controller.go:163] cert-manager/controller "msg"="not starting controller as it's disabled" "controller"="certificatesigningrequests-issuer-selfsigned"
I1220 10:29:40.696651       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificates-readiness"
I1220 10:29:40.696658       1 controller.go:163] cert-manager/controller "msg"="not starting controller as it's disabled" "controller"="gateway-shim"
I1220 10:29:40.696693       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificates-metrics"
I1220 10:29:40.697253       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificaterequests-issuer-ca"
I1220 10:29:40.697471       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificaterequests-issuer-acme"
I1220 10:29:40.697540       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned"
I1220 10:29:40.697963       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificaterequests-issuer-venafi"
I1220 10:29:40.698062       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificates-trigger"
I1220 10:29:40.698111       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificates-request-manager"
I1220 10:29:41.504721       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="challenges"
I1220 10:29:41.504762       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="orders"
I1220 10:29:41.504819       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificates-issuing"
I1220 10:29:41.504853       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificates-key-manager"
I1220 10:29:41.504884       1 controller.go:163] cert-manager/controller "msg"="not starting controller as it's disabled" "controller"="certificatesigningrequests-issuer-acme"
I1220 10:29:41.504942       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificates-revision-manager"
I1220 10:29:41.505066       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="clusterissuers"
I1220 10:29:41.505141       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="ingress-shim"
I1220 10:29:41.505220       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="issuers"
I1220 10:29:41.505467       1 controller.go:186] cert-manager/controller "msg"="starting controller" "controller"="certificaterequests-issuer-vault"
I1220 12:31:42.402384       1 setup.go:219] cert-manager/controller/issuers "msg"="ACME server URL host and ACME private key registration host differ. Re-checking ACME account registration" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-staging" "related_resource_namespace"="prod" "resource_kind"="Issuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-staging" "resource_namespace"="prod" "resource_version"="v1"
I1220 12:31:43.291565       1 setup.go:309] cert-manager/controller/issuers "msg"="verified existing registration with ACME server" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-staging" "related_resource_namespace"="prod" "resource_kind"="Issuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-staging" "resource_namespace"="prod" "resource_version"="v1"
I1220 12:31:43.291617       1 conditions.go:95] Setting lastTransitionTime for Issuer "letsencrypt-staging" condition "Ready" to 2021-12-20 12:31:43.291609136 +0000 UTC m=+7387.349555559
I1220 12:31:43.324585       1 setup.go:202] cert-manager/controller/issuers "msg"="skipping re-verifying ACME account as cached registration details look sufficient" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="letsencrypt-staging" "related_resource_namespace"="prod" "resource_kind"="Issuer" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-staging" "resource_namespace"="prod" "resource_version"="v1"

# kubectl logs ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller-7f4db9965c-ht8t9 -n default -f

I1220 12:53:53.630296       7 status.go:300] "updating Ingress status" namespace="prod" ingress="gateway-echopen-tls" currentValue=[{IP:152.228.169.166 Hostname: Ports:[]}] newValue=[{IP:152.228.169.166 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
I1220 12:53:54.736079       7 status.go:300] "updating Ingress status" namespace="prod" ingress="hapi-echopen-tls" currentValue=[{IP:152.228.169.166 Hostname: Ports:[]}] newValue=[{IP:152.228.169.166 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
I1220 12:53:54.742908       7 status.go:300] "updating Ingress status" namespace="prod" ingress="reader-echopen-tls" currentValue=[{IP:152.228.169.166 Hostname: Ports:[]}] newValue=[{IP:152.228.169.166 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
E1220 12:54:23.467892       7 main.go:90] "invalid ingress configuration" err="host \"sso.mydomain.com\" and path \"/\" is already defined in ingress prod/sso-echopen-tls" ingress="sso-production/prod"
```

Details of Test 2

Same ingress but  without the cert-manager annotation succeeds !

```
# cat ingress-sso-echopen-tls.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
  name: sso-echopen-tls
  namespace: prod
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sso.mydomain.com
    secretName: ingress-echopen-secret-tls
  rules:
  - host: sso.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sso
            port:
              number: 8080



# kubectl create -f ingress-sso-echopen-tls.yaml
ingress.networking.k8s.io/sso-echopen-tls created

# kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE   NAME                  CLASS    HOSTS                                 ADDRESS           PORTS     AGE
prod        gateway-echopen-tls   <none>   gateway.mydomain.com   152.228.169.166   80, 443   7d
prod        hapi-echopen-tls      <none>   hapi.mydomain.com      152.228.169.166   80, 443   9d
prod        reader-echopen-tls    <none>   reader.mydomain.com    152.228.169.166   80, 443   7d
prod        sso-echopen-tls       <none>   sso.mydomain.com       152.228.169.166   80, 443   26s
```

Answer (score 8):

The same domain name probably exist within the ingress. You can delete the ingress by executing following command:

`kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces`

to list installed ingresses

`kubectl delete ingress ingress-name -n ingress-namespace`,

to delete the troublesome ingress

then re-run your command.